# Django 1.8 model migrations have dependency to outdated field type

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration

I used field of specific type from third-party package in my model in Django  1.8 project:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):  
    image = third_party_package.SpecificImageField(...)
```

then I changed field type to standard Django type:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):  
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

Database was successfully migrated to new version of model:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

Then I removed third-party package, because I don't need it any more.

The problem is that migrations still have dependency on third-party package. Makemigrations command can't find third-party package and fails.
As workaround I can install third-party package back and migrate the database, but how I can remove dependency to third-party package without data loss?

Answer (score 4):

I've not tested this but I'd imagine you'd be able to [squash your migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) together which will consolidate them.

```
manage.py squashmigrations myapp 0050
```

You need to pass this the name of your app you want to squash, as well as the number of the migration that you want to squash up to.

What this does is merge together your migration files in to one "super" migration file that will contain all the changes in those migrations, whilst removing those changes that conflict.

> Squashing is the act of reducing an existing set of many migrations down to one (or sometimes a few) migrations which still represent the same changes.
>
> Django does this by taking all of your existing migrations, extracting their Operations and putting them all in sequence, and then running an optimizer over them to try and reduce the length of the list - for example, it knows that CreateModel and DeleteModel cancel each other out, and it knows that AddField can be rolled into CreateModel.

Comment: I've tried squashmigrations command, but it didn't help. "super" migration still has dependency to third-party package. But maybe I just use it incorrectly....

Comment: @Sandro - I wasn't sure if it would still include it or not, (wasn't really something I could test easily), It may be possible to disect the migration it creates yourself and manually edit it to see if you can get your desired result. I'm not sure of a better way

Comment: @Sandro - To expand on my above comment I'm guessing the migration it creates involves a `CreateField` and `AlterField` operation, it may be worth trying to modify these into a single `CreateField`, just be cautious

Answer (score 1):

Since the Field type is only on the Software level, you can make as follow (kind of Trick): just change the `third_party_package.SpecificImageField(...)` with `models.ImageField(...)` in **your migrations script**. It will work perfectly since it will change nothing at the database level, otherwise you will have to optimize your migrations scripts manually till get off the dependency.

Comment: It works. After editing the migrations scripts, it start working ok. But I think this solution is something like a hack... Maybe there is some other more clean way to do this....

Comment: Django migrations does not handle this kind of dependencies automatically even in case the migration depends on a method in external app, you should re-implement the method within the migration script in case you will remove it from the app. In fact Django offers the possibility to update the migrations manually to be able to solve such conflicts. I will recommend you this [article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-migrations-a-primer/) to better understand how it works and that there is nothing bad with resolving conflicts manually.

Comment: @Sandro since it works for you, accept the answer so readers know that's a possible working answer.

Comment: DhiaTN, if the op doesn't believe it is the correct answer to their question then it is perfectly ok to not accept any of them. from what I can tell, your answer will only work when you know exactly what the *database* type of a field is. Which is not always easy to work out with third party packages

Comment: Okay I understand. But just to make my idea clear, in fact it doesn't depend on the field type since it exists no more in the database, it was just about giving a way to migrations scripts to work without the third party dependencies, even if he had replaced the field with integer field, it would worked. I believe *squashmigrations* could solve the problem too, but even in case of squashmigrations you need sometimes to manually apply some modifications to fit your needs because django migrations is not designed to consider this kind of scenarios.